# Retrieve Associated Councils for User's WorkCenter in ae_declarative_authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 7 along with ae_declarative_authorization. I have a WorkCenter table and a Council table joined by a create_joining_table. I need to retrieve all councils associated with the work_center of the user. Here's the code snippet I have:

```
has_permission_on :councils, :to => [:manage] do
  if_attribute :work_center_ids => is_in {user.employee.work_centers.ids}
end
```

However, it only works for the index. Does anyone know why this happens within authorization_rules.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises because it's a has_and_belongs_to_many association, which results in two sets (arrays) instead of a single element and a set. To solve this, another function should be used, which is not is_in but intersects with.

```
has_permission_on :councils, :to => [:manage] do
  if_attribute :work_center_ids => intersects_with { user.employee.work_centers.pluck(:id) }
end
```